# Cannot find the Setup project template in visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

When I try to add setup project for my Window Service project in ultimate VS2010, I cannot find the setup project template in the installed template pane(We have setup template in VS08). I only get two templates, one is InstallShield LE and the other is Visual Studio Installer.

I need your help to find out where I can download the Setup project template.

Thanks
Tony

Comment: I found out thar I need to use the found template function and I found the setup project. Issue resolved. But VS 10 sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out thar I need to use the found template function and I found the setup project